# opencv reduce effects due to light conditions

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am working in a vehicle detection algorithm,in which I am facing issues due to light from environment and from vehicle headlight. I am using background subtraction and findContor methods for identifying vehicles.

In the below picture a vehicle headlight is being detected as an object. If I use threshold method for reducing this problem during night time, then during day time I am facing issues. Can any one suggest me a direction in which I have to do research for solving this problem.[traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO34H.jpg)

Comment: will gaussian Normalization help to reduce this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make adaptive threshholding. Depending your project, you can find the best parameter in the following list to set your threshhold:

- Read the timing on the upper corner of your image, with this you can estimate the amount of daylight, the problem is that on a rainy day it might get as dark as night.
- Check the contrast of the images over time, at night you have higher contrast, due to dark environment and light headlights.
- Check the noise on a small block, at night/dark you have more noise
- Lastly the cheapest is general color of the image, if you can deaktivate the light-balance on the camera.